# Select from list: has elements from another list

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

Consider a data list `data`, and a rule list `rule`. I want to select from `data` all elements that are in `rule`. For example, with

```
data = {a, a + 1, b, b + 2, c, c + 3, a + d, a + c, b + c};
rule = {a, d};
```

I want to select from `data` all elements that contains `a` or `d`. My solution is to invert the result from `FreeQ`, go through the `rule` list, and the pick out the results, like this:

```
HasQL[expr_, lst_] := 
 AnyTrue[Table[Not[FreeQ[expr, lst[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[lst]}], 
  TrueQ]
```

and then `Select[data, HasQL[#, rule] &]` returns the expected result:

> {a, 1 + a, a + d, a + c}

I tried cleaning up the code above:

```
HasQL[d_, r_] := AnyTrue[(!FreeQ[d, #]) & /@ r, TrueQ]
Select[data, HasQL[#, rule] &]
```

Is there a more elegant/clean way to achieve the same result?

Comment: `Select[data, ! FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ rule] &]`?

Comment: @J.M. Nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {a, a + 1, b, b + 2, c, c + 3, a + d, a + c, b + c};

rule = {a, d};
```

Pre-compute `p` for better readability

```
p = Alternatives @@ rule;
```

Using `Pick`

```
Pick[data, Not @* FreeQ[p] /@ data]
```

{a, 1 + a, a + d, a c}

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[Plus[p, _] | p] @ data
```

{a, 1 + a, a + d, a + c}

A generalization (replacing `a + c` with `a * c`)

```
data = {a, a + 1, b, b + 2, c, c + 3, a + d, a * c, b + c};

Cases[_[OrderlessPatternSequence[p, _]] | p] @ data
```

{a, 1 + a, a + d, a c}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {a, a + 1, b, b + 2, c, c + 3, a + d, a + c, b + c};
rule = {a, d};

Select[data, Not@*FreeQ[Alternatives @@ rule]] 

DeleteCases[_?(FreeQ[Alternatives @@ rule])][data]

Extract[data, 
 List /@ First /@ 
   Position[data, Alternatives @@ rule, {1, ∞}]]

StringContainsQ [Alternatives @@ ToString /@ rule] /@ 
  ToString /@ data // Pick[data, #] &
```

---

*Result:*

> {a, 1 + a, a + d, a + c}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {a, a + 1, b, b + 2, c, c + 3, a + d, a + c, b + c};

rule = {a, d};
```

Using `AssociationThread` and `Lookup`:

```
p = Alternatives @@ rule;

pos = Union@Cases[{a_} | {a_, _} :> a]@Position[data, p];

Lookup[AssociationThread[Range@Length@#, #] &@data, pos]

(*{a, 1 + a, a + d, a + c}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using MemberQ:

```
l = {a, a + 1, b, b + 2, c, c + 3, a + d, a + c, b + c} ;
p = Alternatives @@ {a, d} ;
Select[l, MemberQ[#, p, All] &]

(* {a, 1 + a, a + d, a + c} *)
```